Updating Firestore crashes the app in flutter
A the moment I don't understand what happens in my code, because one time i call a function it works and the other time it crashes the app. I have an update function, which I call once in the 'saveAndUpdateNote' function and once in the 'textControllerListenerAngebote' function. By the textController function it works but by the other one it doesn't.
This is the update funtion:
Future<void> updateNoteAngebote({
    required String documentId,
    required String textJob,
    required String textAdresse,
    required String textBezahlung,
    required String textKontakt,
    required String textZeit,
    required String textStadt,
    required String textStadtviertel
  }) async {
    try {
      await notesAngebote.doc(documentId).update({
        textJobFieldName: textJob,
        textAdresseFieldName: textAdresse,
        textBezahlungFieldName: textBezahlung,
        textKontaktFieldName: textKontakt,
        textZeitFieldName: textZeit,
        textStadtviertelFieldName: textStadtviertel,
        textStadtFieldName: textStadt,
      });
      print("yes");
    } catch (e) {
      print('no');
      print(e);
      throw CouldNotUpdateNoteException();
      
    }
  }

This is the rest of the relevant code:
  void _textControllerListenerAngebote() async {
        final note = _note;
        if (note == null) {
          return;
        }
        final textAdresse = _adresseController.text;
        final textZeit = _zeitController.text;
        final textStadt = selectedOptionStadtAngebote;
        final textStadtviertel = selectedOptionStadtteilAngebote;
        final textBezahlung = _bezahlungController.text;
        final textKontakt = _kontaktController.text;
        final textJob = selectedOption;
        await _notesService.updateNoteAngebote(
          documentId: note.documentId,
          textAdresse: textAdresse,
          textStadt: textStadt,
          textStadtviertel: textStadtviertel,
          textJob: textJob,
          textBezahlung: textBezahlung,
          textKontakt: textKontakt,
          textZeit: textZeit,
        );
      }
    
    void _saveNoteIfTextNotEmptyAngebote() async {
        final note= _note;
        final textAdresse = _adresseController.text;
        final textZeit = _zeitController.text;
        final textStadt = selectedOptionStadtAngebote;
        final textStadtviertel = selectedOptionStadtteilAngebote;
        final textBezahlung = _bezahlungController.text;
        final textKontakt = _kontaktController.text;
        final textJob = selectedOption;
        print(note!.documentId)
        await _notesService.updateNoteAngebote(
          documentId: note!.documentId,
          textAdresse: textAdresse,
          textStadt: textStadt,
          textStadtviertel: textStadtviertel,
          textJob: textJob,
          textBezahlung: textBezahlung,
          textKontakt: textKontakt,
          textZeit: textZeit,
        );
      }
    Future<CloudNote> createOrGetExistingNoteAngebote(
          BuildContext context) async {
        final existingNote = _note;
        if (existingNote != null) {
          return existingNote;
        }
        final currentUser = AuthService.firebase().currentUser!;
        final userId = currentUser.id;
        final newNote =
            await _notesService.createNewNoteAngebote(ownerUserId: userId);
        _note = newNote;
        return newNote;
      }
    
      void _setupTextControllerListenerAngebote() {
    _adresseController.removeListener(_textControllerListenerAngebote);
    _adresseController.addListener(_textControllerListenerAngebote);
    _zeitController.removeListener(_textControllerListenerAngebote);
    _zeitController.addListener(_textControllerListenerAngebote);
    _kontaktController.removeListener(_textControllerListenerAngebote);
    _kontaktController.addListener(_textControllerListenerAngebote);
    _bezahlungController.removeListener(_textControllerListenerAngebote);
    _bezahlungController.addListener(_textControllerListenerAngebote);
    _stadtController.removeListener(_textControllerListenerAngebote);
    _stadtController.addListener(_textControllerListenerAngebote);
    _stadtviertelController.removeListener(_textControllerListenerAngebote);
    _stadtviertelController.addListener(_textControllerListenerAngebote);
  }
     @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: const Text('I want to do...'),
            backgroundColor: Colors.green.shade200,
            actions: [
              IconButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  _saveNoteIfTextNotEmptyAngebote();
    
                  Navigator.of(context).pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(
                      notesViewAngeboteRoute, (route) => false);
                  showAutomaticDeleteDialog(context);
                },
                icon: const Icon(Icons.save),
              )
            ],
          ),
          body: ...
               _setupTextControllerListenerAngebote();
                ...

And this is what i get back from the console and as you can see the function worked 29 times as the text got updated from the textController function. but when I pressed the final save button it diden't work and crash eventhough I printed the documetnId and it exists, as you can see in the second picture:


If you need anything else please let me know I will gladly give it to you.

If the app crashes, there is a stack trace. Please look that up on logcat, and add it to your question.

The error message is pretty clear: you're trying to update a document that doesn't exist, which is an error in Firestore.  If you need to create the document, follow the documentation.

but the document exist as you can see in the second picture

@AlexMamo can you please tell me how to look something up on logcat, because I dont't know how to do that - I am using VSCode and not android studio
